# how to set a require for a string to not be null

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereum-classic, string, require

I want to write a require condition for string that string variable could not be null. How to write because string is not taking the != operator

```
function createOrder(address _seller, string memory orderName) public onlySeller returns(bool){
        require(_seller != address(0), "Invalid Address");
        require(orderName != "null", "Invalid Name");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the length of its bytes like this:

```
require(bytes(orderName).length != 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing much stuff with `string` is not allowed yet in solidity, I will attach 2 examples which will help you:

**How to validate if string is empty by converting the string to `bytes` and validating the length:**

```
contract testContract {
    function isStringEmpty(string memory _test) public view returns(bool) {
        bytes memory checkString = bytes(_test);
        if (checkString.length > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**How to compare string by converting the string to `bytes` and `keccak256`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract testContract {
    function stringComparison(string memory _test) public view returns(bool) {
        require(keccak256(bytes(_test)) != keccak256(bytes("null")), "Invalid Name");
    }
}
```

You can wrap this logic into modifier and call it on whatever method you need.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the concept of `null`, `undefined`, `None`, `nil`, etc., does not exist in Solidity, as does in languages like Java, Javascript, Python, Go, etc.

So, what is the `value` used to represent the absence of value in a variable in Solidity? It's the "zero" value, which is the default value for the type.

For example, the default value of a `uint` is 0, the default value of a `bool` is false, the default value of a string is an empty string, the default value of an address is the zero address, which is 40 zeros ("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"), and the default value of a struct is a type with all the default values of the members of that tuple, for example, for the following struct:

```js
struct Person {
    string name; // default or zeroed value of a string is an empty string
    uint age; // default or zeroed value of uint is 0
    bool isActive; // default or zeroed value of bool is false
}
```

So, if I have a reference of Person that has not be initialized and I return it or print it, it would like something like this:

```
("", 0, false)
```

And so on.

So, if you want to check if a string is `null`, you will need to check if a string is empty.
Solidity does not (yet) allow the comparison of dynamic types with the `==` operator.

Dynamic types are types like `string`, `bytes`, `struct`, etc. We cannot use the `==` operator to compare these types.

Static types are types like `int`, `bytes32`, `bool`, `address`, etc. We can use the `==` to compare these types.

To compare these types, we can first encode them with something like `abi.encode` or `abi.encodePacked`, and pass those bytes to the `kecck256` to get a `bytes32` hash of the strings, or any other dynamic type, and compare them with the `==` operator.

The reason why we need to encode it before passing it to the `keccak256` is that `keccak256` is expecting a parameter of `bytes` type. So, if the type we are trying to compare is already `bytes`, we can skip the encoding of it and pass it directly to `keccak256`.

Take a look at the code below to see the usage:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

contract ComparableLibrary {

    function equals(string calldata s1, string calldata s2) public pure returns(bool) {
        // Comparing two strings with the == operator does not compile.
        // return s1 == s2;
        return keccak256(abi.encode(s1)) == keccak256(abi.encode(s2));
    }

    function equals(bytes calldata bs1, bytes calldata bs2) public pure returns(bool) {
        // Comparing two bytes arrays with the == operator does not compile.
        // return bs1 == bs2;
        // No need to encode `bytes`, since that is what keccak256 is expecting.
        return keccak256(bs1) == keccak256(bs2);
    }

    function equals(Person calldata p1, Person calldata p2) public pure returns(bool) {
        // Compare structs with the == dooes not compile
        // return p1 == p2;
        return keccak256(abi.encode(p1)) == keccak256(abi.encode(p2));
    }

    // No need to use keccak256 here to compare, since bytes32 is not a dynamic type
    function equals(bytes32 b1, bytes32 b2) public pure returns(bool) {
        return b1 == b2;
    }

    function equals(uint[] memory a1, uint[] memory a2) public pure returns(bool) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(a1)) == keccak256(abi.encode(a2));
    }

}

struct Person {
    string name;
    uint age;
}
```